# How can i keep the first Image Element of the div to be clicked by default?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I keep the first Element of the div the be clicked by default ? I  have given a div below which contains images and i want the first image of the div to be clicked by default.I am using this as a view in react functional  component

````
```<div className="tv_tabs" style={{ marginLeft: "110px" }}>
                                {
                                    covidhealthImage && covidhealthImage.map((image, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div><img  height="70" width="70" onClick={() => showHeading(index)} src={image} /></div>
                                        );
                                    })
                                }
                            </div>```






  const showHeading = (index) => {
            const heading = healthHeadline[index]
            const headingImage = covidhealthImage[index]
            const captionText = healthCaption[index]
            setNewImage(headingImage)
            setNewCaption(captionText)
            setCurrentHeading(heading)
        }

const [newImage, setNewImage] = useState([]);
    const [newCaption, setNewCaption] = useState([]);
    const [healthHeadline, setHealthHeadline] = useState([])
    const [currentHeading, setCurrentHeading] = useState('')
````

Comment: You are looking at this wrong. You want your state to reflect whatever it is the click does. We have no what showHeading() actually does in your state

Comment: @charlietfl can u check now,i have added some more details.

Comment: So basically what you want. if I understand correctly,  is to set the defaults for the various useStates to be the values that they would be set as when calling `showHeading(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Clicked by default is a differente css? If it's you could use the pseudo-class `:first-child` from css

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Answer (score 0):

you might have to try to use a ref to trigger the event on its own

Ex-

```
simulateClick(e) {
    e.click();

  }
....
<div className="tv_tabs" style={{ marginLeft: "110px" }}>
   {covidHealthImage && covidhealthImage.map((image, index) => {
       return (
            <div ref={this.simulateClick} ><img  height="70" width="70" onClick={() => showHeading(index)} src={image} /></div>
          );
       })
    }
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a hack, just use a ternary operator and just exclude the onclick method on non 0 index values

```php
const [newImage, setNewImage] = useState([]);
const [newCaption, setNewCaption] = useState([]);
const [healthHeadline, setHealthHeadline] = useState([])
const [currentHeading, setCurrentHeading] = useState('')


const showHeading = (index) => {
    const heading = healthHeadline[index]
    const headingImage = covidhealthImage[index]
    const captionText = healthCaption[index]
    setNewImage(headingImage)
    setNewCaption(captionText)
    setCurrentHeading(heading)
}

<div className="tv_tabs" style={{ marginLeft: "110px" }}>
{
    covidhealthImage && covidhealthImage.map((image, index) => {
        return (
            index == 0 ? (
                <div><img  height="70" width="70" onClick={() => showHeading(index)} src={image} /></div>
            ) : (
                <div><img  height="70" width="70" src={image} /></div>
            )
        );
    })
}
</div>
```

Comment: tried this but does not wrk,it makes the other indexes unclickable,thats not what i need?

Comment: @Demogorgon `i want the first image of the div to be clicked by default` but that what the code i provided does